# active job perform_later in rails6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jobs

> *CronJob.perform_later*

rails active job is **work in background**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when you run AnyJob.perform_later it will enqueue the job to perform in background: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html.

You might use sidekiq or resque (or other gems) to execute the background jobs. I'd recommend using sidekiq though.